# Javascript validation when user is focused on text box before commit

Tags: javascript, validation

JavaScript validation rarely comes up in my job and I am a little rusty.

I have a page which confirms overrides for a procedure.There are three elements of relevance here;

1. A Check Box (`cashCheckBox`), which the user checks if he/she wishes to provide input cash
2. the text box where the user places the actual value (`cash`) assuming they checked the check box
3. An Execute button.

Once the check box is checked, is the user clicks anywhere else, the text box displays the default value ($0).  However, when the user checks the check box and then immediately selects the text box (providing no input) then subsequently clicks execute, the user may begin a process in which `cash` is unknowingly selected as "$0".

Is there a simple addition i can add to the `if` condition to accommodate this possibility?

```
function Validate(){
var f=document.frmGeneral;
  if((f.cashCheckBox.checked) && (f.cash.value=="" || snip(f.cash.value,"$")<0))
  {

    alert("cash must be greater than 0");
    f.cash.focus();
    return false;
  }  
return true;                                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Validate(){
    var f=document.frmGeneral;
    if(f.cashCheckBox.checked && +f.cash.value.replace("$","") >= 0)
    {
        alert("cash must be greater than 0");
        f.cash.focus();
        return false;
    }  
    return true;                       
}
```

The main change is to: `+f.cash.value.replace("$","")`.

1. `replace("$","")` removes all `$` characters
2. The `+` preceding `f.cash.value` will force the string to be converted to a number. So `"0"` becomes `0`, or `"abc"` becomes `NaN`
3. With the input cleaned up it then just does a check to make sure the value is greater than zero. If it isn't (i.e. it is `0` *or* `NaN`) then it will fail the check.

### UPDATE

Turns out `0` should be a valid value. Changed to `>= 0`.

Comment: so a Zero value for cash is actually allowed (I need to change the message).  is there some way to find the last item the user was focused on prior to clicking the execute button?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to verify that there is a number in that field then? I just changed the comparison to be `>= 0`. It now verifies that there is a number greater than or equal to zero in that field.

Comment: yeah, that would work.  The onblur event, `javascript:this.value=formatstringDollar(this.value);`, makes it so that neither my validation or yours works for this one situation where a user click the textbox then directly clicks execute.

Comment: How are you specifying the `onblur` event and what is the function `formatstringdollar()`? You probably shouldn't be using the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol for anything in this context.